# initial data in model field

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple model:

```
class MediaLink(models.Model): 
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  subtitle = models.TextField(max_length=2000, unique=False, blank=True)
  byline = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False, blank=True)
  url = models.URLField(unique=False) 
  source = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False)
  source_url = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False, blank=True, null=True, choices=SURL_CHOICES)
  mediatype = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=MEDIATYPE_CHOICES)
  topic = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TOPIC_CHOICES)
  sourceinfo = models.ForeignKey(SourceInfo, blank=True, null=True)
  date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


  def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.title

  class Meta: 
    abstract = True

  class Admin: 
    pass
```

I'd like to set the "subtitle" field so that in each object, its initial data is "`<h3></h3>`". I'm using markdown and having the tags set initially saves me from having to create them in the admin for each record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the default on the field:

```
subtitle = models.TextField(max_length=2000, unique=False, blank=True, default='<h3></h3>')
```

Or if you're using a `ModelForm` you can set it in the `initial` kwarg.

Comment: Thank you. I was using 'initial' instead of 'default' and getting errors. thanx again.